# Getting an error message when I attempt to run seed script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

```
Rails 5.1
```

In my seeds.rb file I have:

```
user = User.new(
    :email =>'random@myapp.com',
    :password =>'xK#986754',
    :password_confirmation =>'xK#986754',
    :first_name =>'John',
    :last_name =>'Smith',
    :role => 1
    :approved => true
)
user.skip_invitation
user.save
```

In my user.rb molde, I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  enum role: [:user, :vip, :admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?


  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessor :email, :password, :first_name, :last_name, :role, :approved

  validates :email, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  validates :role, presence: true

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :user
  end
end
```

In my migration file, I have:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|

      t.string :first_name, null: false
      t.string :last_name, null: false
      t.integer :role, null: false
      t.string :email, null: false

      ## Approved
      t.boolean :approved, :default => 0, :null => false
```

When I try to run the seed file, I get the following error message:

```
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: Mysql2::Error: Field 'first_name' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `users` (`approved`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, '2017-10-23 02:23:36', '2017-10-23 02:23:36')
```

I am obviously using the devise gem

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: What is `attr_accessor` on those fields doing there? That will block access to the underlying database attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `attr_accessor` line. `attr_accessor` is for declaring simple getter/setter methods that wrap instance variables in your class, it cannot be used with a Rails model for  attributes you intend to save to the database. It effectively means that all of the `attr_accessor` attributes exist only in memory and your model will never attempt to write them to the database, hence your error message and all the missing values in your insert query.

Comment: Removing the attr_accessor line solved the problem. I misunderstood how attr_accessor works. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided a first name value and you have told the database to not allow null but have not given a default value.

So why is it that you think you have supplied a value when actually you have not? and when was the last time you ran rails test? which would have picked up on this right from the start?

Your model has attr_accessor's for name but you are not setting the underlying name field from the attr_accessor anywhere so either get rid of the attr_accessor or set the name field from the name attr_accessor in a before_save

What you really want to do is remove all your attr_accessor's
Also why are you mixing coding styles? this is bad practice as it can be confusing to those that follow behind you when it comes to maintentance
In your migration

```
t.boolean :approved, :default => 0, :null => false
```

should really be

```
t.boolean :approved, default: 0, null: false
```

to bring it in to line with the Rails 5 coding style

Comment: I am providing a first_name, what I was misinterpreting is how attr_accessor works.

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper No you didn't you just thiought you had. If you had then the code would work hence the line "So why is it that you think you have supplied a value when actually you have not?" This is about more than just attr_accessors though, it's a about the fact that you hadn't picked this error up much sooner in your automatically generated test suite and suggests a little more knowledge is needed. You are heading for a fall if you continue to mix coding styles and not test